# Нужно переобразовать vbs в c#

Tags: c#, vbscript

```
function encode(s)
  for i = 1 to len(s)
    newtxt = mid(s, i, 1)
    newtxt = chr(asc(newtxt) + 3)
    coded = coded + (newtxt)
  next
  encode = coded
end Function
```

Пример входных и выходных данных

```
text = "texttexttext"
out = encode(text)
msgbox(out)' на выходе wh{wwh{wwh{w
```

Comment: Схема: Открываете любую книгу/сайт/документацию по C# и на первых страницах получаете нужную информацию

Comment: Что делает данная функция? Что она получает на вход? Что должна вернуть? Приведи примеры входных и выходных данных

Comment: text = "texttexttext"; out = encode(text); msgbox(out)| на входе и выходе string

Comment: Пример вызова - это хорошо, добавь пример _результата_. То есть, чему будет равняться `out` из твоего примера. Перенеси это непосредственно в вопрос. А так же добавь ответы на следущие вопросы: _Что делает данная функция? Что она получает на вход? Что должна вернуть?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы перевести функция с одного языка реализации на другой, необходимо знать что происходит внутри функции.

В данном случае функция encode

1. проходит по переданной строке,
2. получает код каждого символа,
3. увеличивает его на 3
4. получает символ, по соответствующему коду
5. собирает новые символы в новую строку, которая и является результатом функции.

Ввиду более широкого инструментария по работе со строками реализации данного алгоритма с помощью C# могут быть различными.

Например, можно воспользоваться циклом либо методом [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) для прохода по строке, методом [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) для собирания результирующей строки, а также использовать то, что `char` - это целочисленный тип, и с ним можно проводить арифметически операции. В итоге можно получить такой вариант:

```
publiс static string Encode(string text)
{
    return string.Concat(text.Select(c => (char)(c + 3)));
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться [заменой символов с помощью регулярного выражения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
publiс static string Encode(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, ".", m => $"{(char)(m.Value[0]+3)}");
}
```